# Re-order <li> based on class and ID

Tags: jquery

I have a number of buttons (dynamically generated) and some list items, grouped by colour like below.

I have some code that when you click the label button it brings the relevant colours to the top of the list. However, it does not keep the numerical order. So, for example, when clicking 'label', I would always want the list item with ID 'blue_1' to appear at the top of the list.

Help! I've been stumped on this for ages.

```js
$('label').on('click', function(){
  
  // re-order colours in numerical order
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="blue" id="blue_1">Blue</li>
  <li class="blue" id="blue_2">Blue</li>  
  <li class="blue" id="blue_3">Blue</li>  
  <li class="blue" id="blue_4">Blue</li>  
  <li class="blue" id="blue_5">Blue</li>  
  <li class="blue" id="blue_6">Blue</li>  
  <li class="red" id="red_1">Red</li> 
  <li class="red" id="red_2">Red</li> 
  <li class="red" id="red_3">Red</li> 
  <li class="red" id="red_4">Red</li> 
  <li class="red" id="red_5">Red</li> 
  <li class="red" id="red_6">Red</li> 
</ul>

<--! these are dynamically generated -->

  <label id="red">Red button</label>
  <label id="blue">Blue button</label>
```

So what I wan to achieve:

Click red button, this list orders to this:

```html
     <ul>
      <li class="red" id="red_1">Red</li>  <!-- always top of the group and in this order-->
      <li class="red" id="red_2">Red</li> 
      <li class="red" id="red_3">Red</li> 
      <li class="red" id="red_4">Red</li> 
      <li class="red" id="red_5">Red</li> 
      <li class="red" id="red_6">Red</li> 
      <li class="blue" id="blue_1">Blue</li> <!-- always top of the group and in this order -->
      <li class="blue" id="blue_2">Blue</li>  
      <li class="blue" id="blue_3">Blue</li>  
      <li class="blue" id="blue_4">Blue</li>  
      <li class="blue" id="blue_5">Blue</li>  
      <li class="blue" id="blue_6">Blue</li>  
    </ul>
```

And vice versa for blue. I always want the ID with 1 to appear top of the colour group, so prepend won't work.

Comment: I don't see any 'label' element in your source code. What is it and what does it do?

Comment: Sorry, I've just corrected. The label element is the button that re-orders the list depending on the ID/colour of the label button clicked. So if label with ID red is clicked, it will bring all the red list items to the top. I just now need to know how to order those red list-items by number.

Comment: Why does your label element end with a closing div tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the data-position attribute to each list item, then use the following jQuery to reorder.

```
 <ul class="listitems">
     <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
     <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
     <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
     <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
 </ul>

$(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
  function sort_li(a, b){
  return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Comment: Does jQuery have a sort method? I've never seen it in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('label').on('click', function () {
    $('.' + this.id).prependTo('ul');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="blue" id="blue_1">Blue1</li>
    <li class="blue" id="blue_2">Blue2</li>
    <li class="blue" id="blue_3">Blue3</li>
    <li class="blue" id="blue_4">Blue4</li>
    <li class="blue" id="blue_5">Blue5</li>
    <li class="blue" id="blue_6">Blue6</li>
    <li class="red" id="red_1">Red1</li>
    <li class="red" id="red_2">Red2</li>
    <li class="red" id="red_3">Red3</li>
    <li class="red" id="red_4">Red4</li>
    <li class="red" id="red_5">Red5</li>
    <li class="red" id="red_6">Red6</li>
</ul>
<label id="red">Red button</label>
<label id="blue">Blue button</label>
```